# Style Plotly Express with CSS

Tags: css, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, dash-bootstrap-components

I'm currently working on a DASH\Plotly app. I am using dash-bootstrap-components with a custom CSS file.
My current problem is, that my plots aren't styled from the CSS file. So they don't perfectly match with the rest of the theme. From what I found this functionality is not possible.
https://plotly.com/python/templates

Is there maybe a possibility to generate a custom plotly.io Template for the plots which is generated from the CSS file? So that the colors, fonts, fontsizes inside the plots match to the rest of the app.